# Size of maximal subgroups in the direct product of finite groups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, direct-product, maximal-subgroup

Let $\pi(G)$ be the set of all prime divisors of the order of a finite group $G$. Prove that: if $M$ is a maximal subgroup in $D=G \times G$ then $\pi(M)=\pi(G)$. 
My attempt:
1) If $G$ is $p$-group then $\pi(M)=p$ for all maximal subgroups in $D$.
Now let $G$ be finite non $p$-group. One type of maximal subgroups in $D$ has the form $M\times G$. For this type of maximal subgroups its clear that they have the same set of prime divisors as $G$. What about other types of maximal subgroups in $D$!!
Any hint how to proceed. 
Thank you.

Comment: Either $M$ contains one of the direct factors (which is the case that you have considered), or it projects onto both factors, and the result still holds.

Comment: Thanks for your respond. Does  $M$ projects onto both factors accrue when $M$ diagonal subgroup of $D$?

Comment: The word accrue means "to accumulate over time" so I have no idea what you are asking! In any case, how is that relevant to the problem? You asked for a hint.

Comment: If $M$ is a subgroup and $\pi_1(M)\neq G$, $\pi_2(M)\neq G$, then $M$ is not maximal, since it is contained in a the proper subgroup $\langle G\times\{e\},M\rangle$ and in the proper subgroup $\langle \{e\}\times G,M\rangle$. If $M$ is the diagonal subgroup, it may or may not be maximal depending on $G$, but it is of course true that the projections of $D=\{(g,g)\mid g\in G\}$ onto the first and second coordinates are surjective. However, that is not really relevant. What is relevant is that if $M$ is maximal, then $M$ must have a quotient that is isomorphic to $G$.

Comment: Thanks Arturo Magidin for the detailed explanation.  Now its clear what is meant by "projects onto both factors". Thank you all